# How to install spanish dictionary for ispell Emacs in OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, emacs, spell-check, spanish

I am trying to install the spanish dictionary for ispell, `espa~nol 1.11`. The most up-to-date source I was able to find is from the `ispanish` package at http://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/espa-nol.

My sequence of steps is as follows:

1) Download source, expand and go to the directory.

2)  In the terminal, `sudo make`. Everything goes smoothly, without errors, but the resulting `espa~nol.hash` file is 13.1 MB, as opposed to the 3.9 MB that the `README` says it should be. From the `README` file:

> The size of the spanish dictionary (espa~nol.hash) is 3.9Mbytes
>   (Solaris 2.7 has this problem). If you get a size much bigger,probably
>   it is due to the sort command of the operating system. In this case we
>   recommend to install the textutils package of GNU and be sure that the
>   sort command that you use is the textutils one.

I figure I can live with a sub-optimal dictionary size, so I carry on with the install with:

3) `sudo make install` which puts the resulting `.hash` and `.aff` files in `/usr/local/lib`, along with the `american` and `english` hashes and affixes;

4) I start `Emacs`, attempt to change the dictionary (`M-x ispell-change-dictionary`) and my new language dictionary does not show in the list.

5) I dive into the `ispell` customizations and find that the dictionaries are placed where `ispell` should find them, so no surprises there. In an old `ispell` changelog i find that it will only recognize valid dictionaries. I am running the latest version if `ispell`.

6) I revisit the dictionary compilation by going into the `Makefile` and find nothing that will point me to the `sort` options, assuming that I somehow screwed up the compilation and that the dictionary is not valid.

I am at a loss right now. The dictionary seems to be actively maintained, so I assume that it works for others, yet I have not been able to get it to work. Am I missing something?

I'm running OS X 10.6.8, GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.35) of 2011-03-09 on black.porkrind.org, Ispell 3.3.02.

Comment: It's been a while since this was posted. Are bumps appropriate?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the dictionary file? Are they the same as for the other dicts?

Comment: All the permissions are the same.